# going from Wifi to 3G -- stops stream and cannot resume in iphone development

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, wifi, 3g

i am developing radio app i have got one issue ie when going from wifi to 3G stops streaming and can't resume again getting wifi or 3G.It is continuous buffering.

Please suggest.

Thanks
Basanth

Answer (score 0):

you must look into apple Reachability API's

Blog tutorial :

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/

http://www.xprogress.com/post-40-iphone-internet-connection-check-wifi-3g-edge-something-like-reachability-h/